# Text appear on left corner of div list styling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have used `transform:rotate();` property to visible vertical but I'm unable to position the list item. I have put first three images in list and 4th item as text

```
<ul>
    <li>img</li>
    <li>img</li>
    <li>img</li>
    <li>p</li>
```

It's possible to position in desktop but not able to position in smaller devices
I tried with position absolute:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: put some code for us  to help you.we don't know wher you stands.

Comment: google would have given you answer quickly than SO!!! -1

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap 
then use this code

```
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xm-12">
       <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xm-1" style="vertical-align: middle;    
display: table-cell;">
              <h1>I need to insert  text here</h1>
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xm-11">
        <ul>
          <li>img</li>
          <li>img</li>
          <li>img</li>
          <li>p</li> 
         </ul>
       </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thanks for the code 

I have done little modification in your code @Saad Mirza

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGQvMY